# How can I subtract time between two time variables?

Tags: r

I have two columns consisting of character values like "22:49" and "00:18". They represent hour and minute time values. How can I get the difference between these two columns? I want my result to be the minutes between the two values.

Comment: Is there a date somewhere, or should all differences be modulus 1440?

Comment: There is no date. Just time.

Answer (score 1):

If your data is in one column, then

```r
dat <- data.frame(x = c("22:49", "00:18"), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
dat$x <- as.POSIXct(sprintf("2000-01-01 %s:00", dat$x))
diffs <- diff(dat$x)
units(diffs) <- "mins"
diffs <- as.numeric(diffs) %% 1440
diffs
# [1] 89
```

With `n` rows of data, this will give you `n-1` differences ... so perhaps you want `c(0, diffs)` at this point.

---

If your data is in two different columns:

```r
dat <- data.frame(x1 = "22:49", x2 = "00:18", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

as.numeric(do.call(difftime, c(unname(
  lapply(dat[,c("x2", "x1")],
         function(d) as.POSIXct(sprintf("2000-01-01 %s:00", d)))), units = "mins"))) %% 1440
# [1] 89
```

Note the order of `x2` then `x1` in this example.

Comment: Or with `lubridate` `with(dat, diff(period_to_seconds(hm(x))/60) %% 1440)`

Answer (score 0):

Use the https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lubridate/lubridate.pdf

Use lubridate package